# Skype is not using pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio, skype

After fresh installing 13.04 at my HP ProBook I can have sound only in one application at a time. 
When I use Skype, there's no sound in Clementine, SMPlayer, etc.

I tried to reinstall ALSA and PulseAudio like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

But with no effect.

In Skype, I have only ALSA (hw:....), there's no 'PulseAudio' option.

Comment: Are all applications configured to use PulseAudio, or is there some that uses ALSA device `hw:x`?

Comment: I don't know why but in Skype I cannot select the `PulseAudio` device - there's no such option.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you running the 64bit version of Ubuntu?

Then try installing 32bit pulseaudio (linking issues cause this incompatibility):

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse0:i386
```

Its important to mention that you need to quit SKYPE and start it again after executing that command otherwise PulseAudio will not be available in the list of devices

Comment: yeah, works for me too, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my LinuxMint 64 bit Mate desktop. I had to:

- install package libpulse0:i386
- do one of these things:

  - Add PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 http://arunraghavan.net/2013/08/pulseaudio-4-0-and-skype/
  - Replace my skype:i386 (I don't know where it was from) with these 2: skype:amd64 skype-bin:i386 (actually it seems, that they added here PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 to .desktop files)